# How to know from which site user have been redirected to our site in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Well i have to disable some controls on my site if it is opened from a particular website otherwise they should remain enabled.

for that i need to know from where have user been redirected to my site so that i can apply necessary filter conditions like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(fromthisSite)
    {
        //....disable some controls
    }
    else
    {
       //.. do nothing
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Request.UrlReferrer`